# Why wont this simple function of mine save?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm putting together a function in MySql. Nothing major. But it wont save. I'm doing this using in HeidiSql.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `mainLinks`(`nid` INT)
    RETURNS varchar(1500)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE aid INT;
    DECLARE atype INT;
    DECLARE aparent INT;
    DECLARE ausername VARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE auserid INT;
    DECLARE aCOUNTRY VARCHAR(2);
    DECLARE aOutput VARCHAR(1500); 

    SELECT id, type, parent, userName, userId, country
    INTO aid, atype, aparent, auserName, auserId, acountry
    FROM arraytest
    WHERE id = nid;

    CASE atype
    WHEN 1 THEN SET aOutput = 'One';
    WHEN 2 THEN SET aOutput = 'Two';
    WHEN 3 THEN SET aOutput = 'Three';
    ELSE 'Neither';
    END;

  RETURN (aOutput);
END
```

It's the `case` that's causing all the problems, and I've tried everything. Moving and removing `;`. But nothing will make it work.

Here's the error:

```
`/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Neither';
    END;

  RETURN (aOutput);
END' at line 26 */`
```

There isn't a line 26 in this function. Can you please help?

**Table with data and other stuff**
[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c377/1)

Comment: Doesn't `CASE` need to be terminated by `END CASE;`?

Comment: @slugonamission I was using this from here, and it worked without it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f976/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your CASE clause all wrong

It should be

```
SET aOutput = CASE atype
              WHEN 1 THEN 'One'
              WHEN 2 THEN 'Two'
              WHEN 3 THEN 'Three'
              ELSE 'Neither'
END;
```

**Edit**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `mainLinks`(`nid` INT)
    RETURNS varchar(1500)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
    DECLARE aid INT;
    DECLARE atype INT;
    DECLARE aparent INT;
    DECLARE ausername VARCHAR(32);
    DECLARE auserid INT;
    DECLARE aCOUNTRY VARCHAR(2);
    DECLARE aOutput VARCHAR(1500); 

    SELECT id, type, parent, userName, userId, country
    INTO aid, atype, aparent, auserName, auserId, acountry
    FROM arraytest
    WHERE id = nid;

    SET aOutput = CASE atype
        WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT (auserName, ' other stuff')
        WHEN 2 THEN auserName
        WHEN 3 THEN 'other stuff'
        ELSE 'default stuff'
    END;
    RETURN (aOutput);
END
```

Something *very* similar tests OK on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c810/2)

Comment: This works, but I need to encrypt output at the very end before returning it. Which is why I used the approach above. Also, when it comes to `1` I need to set more stuff for `aOutput`. set `aOutput = aOutput + more here`

Comment: I'm confused. Your fiddle works fine and appends extra things for case 1 - what's the problem?

Comment: This function is different. There are few things added. The function in there is what we were working on a few hours ago.

Comment: I added the `case` here, and have been at this past hour and half :)

Comment: OK, so the problem lies in the things you've added. What have you added?

Comment: There's nothing at www.sqlfiddle.com apart from the `case`. This is what I'm seeing there: `CREATE FUNCTION mylink(n INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(512) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN CONCAT('<a href=foo.php?id=',n,'>');

CREATE FUNCTION myfunction(n INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(512) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN CASE n
    WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT(mylink(1), mylink(2), mylink(7))
    WHEN 2 THEN mylink(3)
    WHEN 3 THEN mylink(10)
END;
`

Comment: At this link. In the question. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c377/1 There's no `case`, but the other part still remains (before I added the case).

Comment: OK, sorry - too many fiddles around here! The one at 23c77 in your most recent comment works. You want to change it to do something like the one at 4f976 from your response to slugonamission. Is that right?

Comment: Umm... I'm just trying to get the `case` to work :) See the case in my question? Just trying to get that to work the same way. The function there is the same here. Its only lacking the case.

Comment: That's a good one :) Never thought of doing it that way. Actually, I was fiddling with doing another function that was called from this one. But your approach is really innovative :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31337/discussion-between-norman-and-nurdglaw)

Answer (score 0):

It's the case statement which is causing you errors

```
CASE atype
WHEN 1 THEN SET aOutput = 'One';
WHEN 2 THEN SET aOutput = 'Two';
WHEN 3 THEN SET aOutput = 'Three';
ELSE 'Neither';
END;
```

Should be

```
CASE atype
    WHEN 1 THEN SET aOutput = 'One'
    WHEN 2 THEN SET aOutput = 'Two'
    WHEN 3 THEN SET aOutput = 'Three'
    ELSE 'Neither'
END CASE;
```

Comment: This does not work. I arrived at this version sometime ago :)

Comment: Yes the same error. I've linked to the fiddle with the table data in my edited question.